# How to populate my Spinner based on the value on my TextView?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, spinner

I am new to Android programming and I'm working on a project that fetches data from MySQL DB.

Now, I have two java files. The first fetches employees and their id, it has Spinners that when clicked, it copies the value of the name and id of the employees to the TextViews and transfer the data to the next Activity through Intent.

While the second fetches employees' schedule based on the employee id. This second activity should populate Spinner based on the id of the employees that was passes from the first activity.

First Activity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    JSONObject jObj;
    JSONArray jArray;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList < String > aestheticianList;
    ArrayList < Items > items;
    Button btnTransact;
    String service_name, price;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_farmers_aesthetician);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        btnTransact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTransact);
        btnTransact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(cp000l3.flawlessfaceandbodyclinic.project.transact.FarmersAestheticianActivity.this,
                cp000l3.flawlessfaceandbodyclinic.project.transact.FarmersDateTimeActivity.class);
                String service_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.service_name)).getText().toString();
                String price = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                String full_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.full_name)).getText().toString();
                String aid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.aid)).getText().toString();

                i.putExtra("service_name", service_name);
                i.putExtra("price", price);
                i.putExtra("full_name", full_name);
                i.putExtra("aid", aid);

                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

        TextView txtService_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.service_name);
        TextView txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        service_name = i.getStringExtra("service_name");
        price = i.getStringExtra("price");

        txtService_name.setText(service_name);
        txtPrice.setText(price);
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            items = new ArrayList < Items > ();
            aestheticianList = new ArrayList < String > ();

            try {
                jObj = JSONParser.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.9:8013/flawlessadmin/storescripts/transaction/final/get_aesthetician2.php");
                try {
                    jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("aesthetician");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Items item = new Items();

                        item.setFull_name(jObj.optString("full_name"));
                        item.setAid(jObj.optString("aid"));

                        items.add(item);
                        aestheticianList.add(jObj.optString("full_name"));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_aesthetician);

            spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (FarmersAestheticianActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, aestheticianList));

            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView txt_full_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.full_name);
                    TextView txt_aid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aid);

                    txt_full_name.setText(items.get(position).getFull_name());
                    txt_aid.setText(items.get(position).getAid());

                    ////////////////////////////////

                    ////////////////////////////////
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    JSONObject jObj;
    JSONArray jArray;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList < String > dateTimeList;
    ArrayList < Items > items;
    Button btnTransact;
    String service_name, price, full_name, aid, tid;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_farmers_datetime);

        new DownService().execute();

        btnTransact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTransact);
        btnTransact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(cp000l3.flawlessfaceandbodyclinic.project.transact.FarmersDateTimeActivity.this,
                cp000l3.flawlessfaceandbodyclinic.project.transact.FarmersConfirmationActivity.class);
                String service_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.service_name)).getText().toString();
                String price = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                String aid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.aid)).getText().toString();
                String full_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.full_name)).getText().toString();
                String tid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tid)).getText().toString();
                String datetime = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetime)).getText().toString();

                i.putExtra("service_name", service_name);
                i.putExtra("price", price);
                i.putExtra("aid", aid);
                i.putExtra("full_name", full_name);
                i.putExtra("tid", tid);
                i.putExtra("date_time", datetime);

                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

        TextView txtService_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.service_name);
        TextView txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        TextView txtFull_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.full_name);
        TextView txtAid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aid);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        service_name = i.getStringExtra("service_name");
        price = i.getStringExtra("price");
        full_name = i.getStringExtra("full_name");
        aid = i.getStringExtra("aid");

        txtService_name.setText(service_name);
        txtPrice.setText(price);
        txtFull_name.setText(full_name);
        txtAid.setText(aid);
    }
    private class DownService extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            items = new ArrayList < Items > ();
            dateTimeList = new ArrayList < String > ();

            /////////////////////////
            List < NameValuePair > param = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aid", aid));
            /////////////////////////

            try {
                String jObj = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest2("http://192.168.1.9:8013/flawlessadmin/storescripts/transaction/final/get_time2.php", "GET", param); //("http://192.168.1.9:8013/flawlessadmin/storescripts/transaction/final/get_time.php");
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jObj);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Items item = new Items();

                        item.setDateTime(jsonObj.optString("date_time"));
                        item.setTid(jsonObj.optString("tid"));

                        items.add(item);
                        dateTimeList.add(jsonObj.optString("date_time"));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_datetime);

            spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (FarmersDateTimeActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, dateTimeList));

            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView txt_datetime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetime);
                    TextView txt_tid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tid);

                    txt_datetime.setText(items.get(position).getDateTime());
                    txt_tid.setText(items.get(position).getTid());

                    ////////////////////////////////

                    ////////////////////////////////
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, nothing at the moment. As you can see, I tried to use NameValuePair in the second, but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

in second Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = extras.getInt("Id");  // get the id passed from first activty
```